# "The Transport Failed to Connect to the Server" when trying to send spreadsheet via SMTP

Tags: excel, vba, email, smtp

I'm attempting to send an Excel spreadsheet via SMTP using the code displayed below. However, whenever I run the code I receive the error **"The Transport Failed to Connect to the Server"**.

Here is the code:

```
    Sub CommandButton_Click()
Dim CDO_Mail_Object As Object
Dim CDO_Config As Object
Dim SMTP_Config As Variant
Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String

Email_Subject = "Trying to send email using CDO"
Email_Send_From = "xxxxx@yahoo.com"
Email_Send_To = "xxxxx@hotmail.com"
Email_Cc = ""
Email_Bcc = ""
Email_Body = "Congratulations!!!! You have successfully sent an e-mail using CDO !!!!"

Set CDO_Mail_Object = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

On Error GoTo debugs
Set CDO_Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
CDO_Config.Load -1
Set SMTP_Config = CDO_Config.Fields
With SMTP_Config
'please put your server name below
.Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
.Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/smtpusetls") = True
.Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxxxx@yahoo.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "xxxxx"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.mail.yahoo.co.uk"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
.Update
End With

With CDO_Mail_Object
Set .Configuration = CDO_Config
End With

CDO_Mail_Object.Subject = Email_Subject
CDO_Mail_Object.From = Email_Send_From
CDO_Mail_Object.To = Email_Send_To
CDO_Mail_Object.TextBody = Email_Body
CDO_Mail_Object.cc = Email_Cc 'Use if needed
CDO_Mail_Object.BCC = Email_Bcc 'Use if needed
'CDO_Mail_Object.AddAttachment FileToAttach 'Use if needed
CDO_Mail_Object.send

debugs:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Are there errors in the above code (I have enabled the Microsoft CDO Library contained in Excel > Tools > References) or are there errors in the SMTP credentials I have provided?
Am I using the wrong Yahoo SMTP server (should I use .com)?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this Works in your case, but I recently saw this in a similar post.

Try removing the uppercase letters in Your schema url?

"Microsoft.Com" -> "microsoft.com"